# How do I overlap shapes on top of each other in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm cleaning up an old hangman project, but I noticed that the torso gets drawn on top of the head/face. Is there a way to get the head/face to appear on top of the torso? I tried switching the order of "head" and "torso" in the array named "drawArray", but all that does is change the order that each body part is drawn (instead of drawing the head/face first, it draws the torso first, which isn't what I want)

```
//loads everything in onload function when page loads
window.onload = function () {
    //array of alphabet letters to create keyboard UI with
    var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
        'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
        't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

    //different topics that player can guess from
    var categories;    

    //the chosen or selected category (chosen randomly)     
    var chosenCategory;     
    var getHint;    

    //the chosen word      
    var word;              
    var guess;

    //stored guesses            
    var guesses = [ ];      
    var lives; 

    //counts number of correct guesses            
    var counter; 

    //number of spaces ('-') in word          
    var space;              

    //getting elements by id and assigning them to variables
    var showLives = document.getElementById("lives");
    var getHint = document.getElementById("hint");
    var showClue = document.getElementById("clue");

    //create alphabet letter keyboard buttons
    var keyboard = function () {
        myButtons = document.getElementById('keyboard');
        letters = document.createElement('ul');

        for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            letters.id = 'alphabet';
            list = document.createElement('li');
            list.id = 'letter';
            list.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
            check();
            myButtons.appendChild(letters);
            letters.appendChild(list);
        }
    }

    //choosing a category
    var selectCat = function () {
        if (chosenCategory === categories[0]) {
            categoryName.innerHTML = "The chosen category is cities";
        } else if (chosenCategory === categories[1]) {
            categoryName.innerHTML = "The chosen category is films";
        } else if (chosenCategory === categories[2]) {
            categoryName.innerHTML = "The chosen category is food";
        }
    }

    //create the hidden word in underscores
    result = function () {
        wordHolder = document.getElementById('hiddenWord');
        correct = document.createElement('ul');

        for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            correct.setAttribute('id', 'hiddenWord');
            guess = document.createElement('li');
            guess.setAttribute('class', 'guess');

            if (word[i] === "-") {
                guess.innerHTML = "-";
                space = 1;
            } else {
                guess.innerHTML = "_";
            }

            guesses.push(guess);
            wordHolder.appendChild(correct);
            correct.appendChild(guess);
        }
    }

    //displaying player's lives
    comments = function () {
        showLives.innerHTML = "You have " + lives + " lives";

        if (lives < 1) {
            showLives.innerHTML = "Game Over";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++) {
            if (counter + space === guesses.length) {
                showLives.innerHTML = "You Win!";
            }
        }
    }

    //function to perform the drawing action for the hangman figure
    var animate = function () {
        var drawMe = lives ;
        drawArray[drawMe]();
    }

    //hangman
    canvas =  function(){
        myStickman = document.getElementById("stickman");
        context = myStickman.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "#6F706F";
        context.lineWidth = 2;
    };

    head = function(){
        myStickman = document.getElementById("stickman");
        context = myStickman.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(60, 25, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.fillStyle = '#CDFCFF';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 2;
      context.strokeStyle = '#6F706F';
        context.stroke();

      //left eye
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(53, 28, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.fillStyle = '#6F706F';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();

      //right eye
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(64, 25, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.fillStyle = '#6F706F';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();
    }

    torso = function() {
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(56, 30, 20, 50);
      context.fillStyle = '#6F706F';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();
    }

    draw = function($pathFromx, $pathFromy, $pathTox, $pathToy) {
        context.moveTo($pathFromx, $pathFromy);
        context.lineTo($pathTox, $pathToy);
        context.stroke(); 
    }

    frame1 = function() {
        draw (0, 150, 150, 150);
    };

    frame2 = function() {
        draw (10, 0, 10, 600);
    };

    frame3 = function() {
        draw (0, 5, 70, 5);
    };

    frame4 = function() {
        draw (60, 5, 60, 15);
    };

    rightArm = function() {
        draw (76, 45, 94, 50);
    };

    leftArm = function() {
        draw (58, 45, 40, 50);
    };

    rightLeg = function() {
        draw (75, 70, 77, 100);
    };

    leftLeg = function() {
        draw (60, 70, 58, 100);
    };

    drawArray = [rightLeg, leftLeg, rightArm, leftArm,  torso,  head, frame4, frame3, frame2, frame1]; 


    //checking if keyboard button is clicked and performs correct action
    check = function () {
        list.onclick = function () {
            var geuss = (this.innerHTML);
            this.setAttribute("class", "active");
            this.onclick = null;

            for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                if (word[i] === geuss) {
                    guesses[i].innerHTML = geuss;
                    counter += 1;
                } 
            }
            var j = (word.indexOf(geuss));

            if (j === -1) {
                lives -= 1;
                comments();
                animate();
            } else {
                comments();
            }
        }
    }

    //gameplay
    play = function () {
        //categories (cities, films, food)
        categories = [
            ["new-york-city", "los-angeles", "london", "tokyo", "brussels", "shanghai", "beijing", "paris", "vancouver", "jakarta"],
            ["harry-potter", "finding-nemo", "jaws", "charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory", "the-breakfast-club", "spirited-away", "up", "toy-story", "forrest-gump", "the-shining"],
            ["sushi", "gelato", "banana", "chocolate", "strawberry", "sandwich", "grapes", "cheese-stick", "rice", "burrito"]
        ];

        chosenCategory = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)];
        word = chosenCategory[Math.floor(Math.random() * chosenCategory.length)];
        word = word.replace(/\s/g, "-");
        keyboard();

        guesses = [ ];
        lives = 10;
        counter = 0;
        space = 0;
        result();
        comments();
        selectCat();
        canvas();
    }

    play();

    //giving a hint
    hint.onclick = function() {
        hints = [
            ["Skyscraper wonderland", "Starry night", "Historic clock tower", "Neon and futuristic", "Chocolate lovers", "Global financial hub", "The Forbidden City", "Vintage romance", "Shivers up your spine", "Capital of an island"],
            ["Wizards and magic", "Lost fish", "Great white shark", "Chocolate river", "1980's classic", "Anime", "Balloon home", "Talking toys", "RUN", "Here's Johnny!"],
            ["Raw", "Italian dessert", "Also a type of slug", "Solid and liquid", "Fondue please", "Many layers", "Make wine", "Stringy", "Too small to count", "Wrap it up"]
        ];

        var categoryIndex = categories.indexOf(chosenCategory);
        var hintIndex = chosenCategory.indexOf(word);
        showClue.innerHTML = "Clue: " +  hints [categoryIndex][hintIndex];
    };

    //resetting the game
    document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
        correct.parentNode.removeChild(correct);
        letters.parentNode.removeChild(letters);
        showClue.innerHTML = "";
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use compositing:

https://www.w3resource.com/html5-canvas/html5-canvas-compositing.php

Try adding this to your torso function:

```
context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
```

Comment: Were you able to get the torso to display behind the head?

Comment: Yes! It worked :) I was also wondering how I'd disable the keyboard buttons when the lives hits 0. But if it's better, I can make a separate post about that.